# Problem with drag and drop in react-beautiful-dnd, it only recognizes the top row as Droppable when line breaks

Tags: reactjs, drag-and-drop, draggable, droppable, react-beautiful-dnd

When flex wrap is enabled, the droppable doesn't recognize that a new line has appeared, and I can only drop the item on the line above. Does anyone know if it's possible to achieve this with this library?
I would like it to have the normal behavior of expanding the drop area when line breaks.

I'm new to the company and I've already taken on this problem to solve. I would greatly appreciate anyone who can help me...

[image]

```
      <DragDropContextWrap
        alternatives={words}
        state={state}
        setState={setState}
        currentProgram={currentProgram}
      >
        <Flex flexDir={"column"} gap={3} mt="32px">
          <Droppable droppableId="sentence" direction="horizontal">
            {(provided) => (
              <Flex
                ref={provided.innerRef}
                minW={["300px", "625px"]}
                minH={"70px"}
                bg="white"
                p="8px 16px"
                borderRadius="8px"
                border="1.5px solid #CBD5E0"
                flexWrap="wrap"
                alignItems="flex-start"
              >
                {state.sentence.map((item, index) => (
                  <Draggable
                    key={item.id}
                    draggableId={String(item.id)}
                    index={index}
                  >
                    {(provided, snapshot) => (
                      <Flex
                        ref={provided.innerRef}
                        {...provided.draggableProps}
                        {...provided.dragHandleProps}
                        p="8px 8px"
                        borderRadius="8px"
                        backgroundColor={snapshot.isDragging ? "#ff5e5e" : ""}
                        minWidth="fit-content"
                      >
                        <Text32px color="primary">{item.text}</Text32px>
                      </Flex>
                    )}
                  </Draggable>
                ))}
                {provided.placeholder}
              </Flex>
            )}
          </Droppable>
        </Flex>

        <DragOptionsBox
          alternatives={state.items}
          droppableId="items"
          inactiveDrag={inactiveDrag}
        />
      </DragDropContextWrap>
```

I am using Chakra UI for styling.